# Firebase - JSON sent object results escaped

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

When I `.set(jsonObject)` into Firebase DB, using angularfire2, the object is escaped(backslashes are added before each double quote).
When I manually add the `jsonObject` into DB(console.firebase.google.com) everything works fine.

```js
    let obj = {
      key0 : 0,
      key1 : 1
    };
    console.log(obj);
    
    let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(jsonObject);
```

```
// af is AngularFire instance
af.database.object("/myList/0").set(jsonObject)
```

The result in Firebase DB Console is: `"{\"key0\":0,\"key1\":1}"`

But I get the expected result when I go to Firebase DB Console and replace the escaped object with the values from `console.log(jsonObject)`.

What is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are setting the value this way:

```
let obj = {
  key0 : 0,
  key1 : 1
};
let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
af.database.object("/myList/0").set(jsonObject);
```

The value at `/myList/0` will be a string:

```
{"key0":0,"key1":1}
```

The values shown in the console will be shown as JSON. When formatted as JSON, the above string value will be:

```
"{\"key0\":0,\"key1\":1}"
```

If you set the value using the object and not the JSON string, you should see the behaviour you are expecting:

```
 let obj = {
  key0 : 0,
  key1 : 1
};
af.database.object("/myList/0").set(obj);
```